# ScalaTest : inject implicit variable

Tags: scala, scalatest, implicit

I am from Java background and I am trying to write UnitTests using Scala.

My class is as follows :

```
import com.softwaremill.sttp.{HttpURLConnectionBackend, Uri, sttp}

class MyClient(endpoint: String, principal: String) {

  private implicit val serialization = org.json4s.native.Serialization
  private implicit val backend = HttpURLConnectionBackend()

  def getDataSet(id: String) : Option[DataSet] = {
      //sttp.get(url).send <-- will use 'bakend'
  }
}
```

here the implicit variable 'backend' is used to plugin the HTTP Client implementation.

In the UnitTest I am supposed to plugin the **SttpBackendStub** .

```
implicit val testingBackend = SttpBackendStub.synchronous
        .whenRequestMatches(_.uri.path.startsWith("/dataSet"))
        .thenRespond(dataSetJson)

val client = new MyClient("http://dummy", "dummy")
```

However when I initiate MyClient instance, it will still use **HttpURLConnectionBackend** instead of **SttpBackendStub**

Is there workaround to ingest 'testingBackend' into the MyClient during testing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of implicit here is making you think the problem is more complicated than it is. You're instantiating `HttpURLConnectionBackend` directly in `MyClient` so that's the "backend" you're going to get. If you want to use a different one, you'll have to pass it in to MyClient. You can give it a default value for production use but pass in a mock when you instantiate it in your test.

```
class MyClient(endpoint: String, principal: String,
    implicit val backend: BackendInterface = HttpURLConnectionBackend) {

  private implicit val serialization = org.json4s.native.Serialization

  def getDataSet(id: String) : Option[DataSet] = {
      //sttp.get(url).send <-- will use 'bakend'
  }
}
```

And in your test:

```
val testingBackend = SttpBackendStub.synchronous
        .whenRequestMatches(_.uri.path.startsWith("/dataSet"))
        .thenRespond(dataSetJson)

val client = new MyClient("http://dummy", "dummy", testingBackend)
```